# CSS Multiple hover button issues

Tags: html, css

The issue here being that I would like all of the elements from the list to be right below eachother instead of there being a space, and I don't want every li to pop-up when you move over 1 button, just the ones corresponding to each other.

CSS:

```
#uphead {list-style: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px 0px;}
#partnumbers {list-style-type: none;}
#partnumbers a {padding: 2px 10px; width: 220px; display:block;}
#partnumbers li {list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 220px;}
#partnumbers li ul {position: relative; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; float:left; z-index:20;}
#pn {display: none; background: url('../../../images/pn_box.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 200px 40px; height: 40px; width: 150px; position: relative; z-index: 20; margin: -40px 225px;}
#partnumbers:hover li ul li{display: block; padding: 10px 30px 0px; position: relative; z-index: 500; opacity: 0.9;}
.odd {background:#f4f3f0;}
.even {background:#eae9e6;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="underpic">
<ul id="uphead">
    <li>
        iPhone 4 &amp; 4s</li>
</ul>
<ul id="partnumbers">
    <li>
        <a class="even">MSR</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="pn">
                LP4MS - PH4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="odd">MSR, 1D Scanner</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="pn">
                LP4 - PH4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="even">MSR, 1D Scanner with Bluetooth</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="pn">
                LP4BT - PH4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="odd">MSR, 2D Code Scanner</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="pn">
                LP4C2D - PH4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="even">MSR, 2D Code Scanner with Bluetooth</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="pn">
                LP4C2DBT - PH4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix 1: Remove padding from `#partnumbers li ul`

Fix 2: Change `#partnumbers:hover li ul li` to `#partnumbers li:hover ul li`

I'll try and copy most of the styles I played with, but I might miss some, also I'm only using the firefox specific prefixes, you need to add all the browser prefixes you want to support:

```
#partnumbers {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#partnumbers > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #CECDCB;
}

#partnumbers a {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#partnumbers li ul {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: -7px;
    z-index: 20;
}
#partnumbers li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
}
#pn {
    background: url("http://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/ipc/images/pn_box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% 100% transparent;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: If I also wanted to get a border around each of the boxes how could I go about doing that? i keep trying but it doesn't go around each li... and I also can't get the padding to work properly on each 'button' (i want to extend it more to the left)

Comment: Part of the border issue is that the a tag contained within the li tags are too wide.  Remove the width from `#partnumber li` and let it grow automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/mWACL/2/  remove either the red or green border depending on which you wanted to keep.

Comment: The padding is still an issue...maybe you could better help me if you saw the page: http://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/cmspages/ipc_lineapro4.aspx also, what does the '>' mean?

Comment: `#pn { margin: -32px -215px; }` and `#partnumbers li:hover ul li { padding: 10px; }`

Comment: That doesn't totally fix the issues.  It doesn't vertically center the tooltip if the text is two lines, and the tooltip doesn't resize to fit the content.

Comment: I started playing with it some more.  If I were you, I would make the following changes: stop floating everything.  Put position:relative on the parent li's, position:absolute;top:-10px;right:100%; on the child ul's.

Comment: Updated answer with more styles.  That should put you in a good starting point.  From there, I would get rid of the background image on the tooltip.  Give it a white background, border-radius to round the edges, then use `:after` on it to place an image for the arrow portion of it only.  Older versions of IE will see a square tooltip, which is a good trade-off.

Comment: To answer your previous question, '>' means a direct child.  So #partnumber > li will target the li's that are direct children of partnumber, but not the great grandchildren that `#partnumber li ul li` would target.

Comment: Holy crap... thats amazing... you think you could possibly add some comments so that I know what does what for the future?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the CSS code...

```
#uphead {list-style: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px 0px;}
#partnumbers {list-style-type: none;}
#partnumbers a {padding: 2px 10px; width: 220px; display:block;}
#partnumbers li {list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 220px;}
#partnumbers li ul {position: relative; float:left; z-index:20;}
#pn {display: none; background: url('../../../images/pn_box.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 200px 40px; height: 40px; width: 150px; position: relative; z-index: 20; margin: -40px 225px;}
#partnumbers li:hover ul li{display: block; padding: 10px 30px 0px; position: relative; z-index: 500; opacity: 0.9;}
.odd {background:#f4f3f0;}
.even {background:#eae9e6;}
```